# what's less expensive? Reconstruction of whole HTML table or reordering of it's rows?

Tags: jquery, html, performance

I have a big table rendered in a page with data.
Now when user clicks on the header, I need to sort the rows.
At this point I have two options. 
1. I may run sorting on JavaScript data and reconstruct whole table with that.
2. I may run sorting on JavaScript data, but just reshuffle the rows of table which was already constructed.

Which way is less expensive considering browser efficiency?

TIA.

Comment: Both seems to be quite expensive, if the table is large. I normally prefer to let the server rebuild the table, in right order via an Ajax call. The UI will not freeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOM manipulation in general is pretty expensive, usually. It appears that creating elements from scratch is a more expensive process than simply rearranging already existing elements. See the following mini performance test:

```js
const trs = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
const table = document.querySelector('table');

const t0 = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  table.appendChild(trs[i % 4]);
  table.appendChild(trs[(1 + i) % 4]);
  table.appendChild(trs[(2 + i) % 4]);
  table.appendChild(trs[(3 + i) % 4]);
}

const t1 = performance.now();

for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  table.innerHTML = `
  <tr><td>content 4</td><td>content</td><td>content</td></tr>
  <tr><td>content 3</td><td>content</td><td>content</td></tr>
  <tr><td>content 2</td><td>content</td><td>content</td></tr>
  <tr><td>content 1</td><td>content</td><td>content</td></tr>
  `;
}

const t2 = performance.now();

console.log('Reshuffling:', t1 - t0);
console.log('Creating from scratch:', t2 - t1);
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>content 1</td><td>content</td><td>content</td></tr>
<tr><td>content 2</td><td>content</td><td>content</td></tr>
<tr><td>content 3</td><td>content</td><td>content</td></tr>
<tr><td>content 4</td><td>content</td><td>content</td></tr>
</table>
```

That said, unless your table has *thousands* of elements, it's probably not something worth worrying about.

Comment: Amusingly, omitting the end tags (which aren't needed) is marginally, but consistently, faster than having them in. I wonder if it's simply due to the additional bytes having to be read. I also wonder if a bunch of createElement() and appendChild() calls is going to make much more of a difference compared to innerHTML. Either way, even without profiling it does seem intuitive that reconstructing would be more expensive since you're effectively replacing the entire table with a brand new one, and that means replacing *all* of its rows and cells.